# Display name instead of id Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two tables; RTAList and RTARegCompany. RTARegCompany contains foreign key rta_id referencing RTAList.

```
    Schema::create('rta_list', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('rta_id');
        $table->string('rta_name');
        $table->string('rta_address');
        $table->string('rta_phone');
        $table->string('rta_email')->unique();
        $table->integer('count'); 
        $table->timestamps();
    });

 Schema::create('rta_reg_company', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('company_id');
        $table->integer('rta_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('rta_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('rta_lists')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('company_name');
        $table->string('company_isin');
        $table->string('company_script');
        $table->string('company_address');
        $table->string('company_phone');
        $table->string('company_email');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have to models RTAList and RTARegCompany.

```
protected $table = 'rta_list';
protected $fillable = ['rta_name', 'rta_address','rta_phone','rta_email'];



 protected $table = 'rta_reg_company';
protected $fillable = ['rta_id', 'company_name','company_isin','company_script','company_address','company_phone','company_email'];


public function rtaname(){
    return $this->belongsTo(RTAList::class);
 }
```

Now, I want to show rta_name while adding RTA Registered Company. But i get error 'Trying to get nom-property;

In RTARegController, I have written this code..

```
 $rta = RTAList::where('rtaname')->get();
```

in add_company.blade.php, i want to show rta_name

```
  <input type="text" name="rta_id" id="rta_id" value="{{ $rta->rtaname->rta_name }}" disabled>
```

Help me to solve this problem...

Comment: What does your query (i.e. `RTAList::where()`) return? Doesn't this method require more arguments? At least `::where('colname', 'value')`?

Comment: I didn't understood

Comment: Your query is confusing you are trying to get data from `RTAList` and want to show  `rta_name` which is present in `RTAList` , what is the purpose to call `rtaname`?

Comment: So, How can I get rta_name from rta_id? I have rta_id..  $rta = RTAList::where(['rta_id'=>$rta_id])->get();

Comment: public function rtaname(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RTAList',rta_id);
 }